# Javascript function works in FF, Opera etc, fails in IE8 - how to fix

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I have the following function (worked in IE6 but is broken in IE8)

```
function implode() { var str = '';
    for(item in globvars)  //<- IE8 wets itself here ...
       str+= '\n' + globvars[item]+';';
    return str+'\n';
}
```

It seems an innocuous little function, but IE8 dosent grok it. Can anyone show me how to rewrite this so it work in IE8 (as well as the other browsers)?

**[Edit]**

At the begining of the script (i.e. first line after the  tag, I have defined the globvars like this:

```
var globvars = new Array();  // This should give globvars global scope
```

The error from IE8 is:

Object does not support this action

Comment: I don't see where `globvars` is defined, do you have additional code?

Comment: How does it fail? Any error messages?

Comment: please look ,hope it will be helpful for IE 8 issues 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862193/javascript-global-variables/4862268#4862268

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I DO NOT have a variable named item anywhere else in my script

You will, however, have an element with `id="item"` or `name="item"`. IE mirrors elements with an id/name not just as `document.item` but also `window.item`. (Obviously it's bad practice to rely on either.)

So when you say `item=` without telling it you want a `var`, silly IE thinks you're trying to assign to the existing HTMLElement with that id/name sitting in the `window`, and throws a fit because elements aren't writable. This is one reason to always use `var` even for global variables.

You shouldn't use `for...in` to iterate an Array. It doesn't do what you think. It may return the array items in the wrong order, and potentially unexpected non-numeric properties. Always use the plain old `for (var i= 0; i<array.length; i++)` loop for getting the items in an Array; `for...in` is only for `Object` used as a mapping.

Anyhow, JavaScript's built-in `join()` almost does the work for you:

```
function implode() {
    return '\n'+globvars.join(';\n')+';\n';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I use this syntax in IE all the time with no problem.

Have you tried:

```
function implode() { var str = ''; 
    for(var item in globvars)  //<- IE8 wets itself here ... 
       str+= '\n' + globvars[item]+';'; 
    return str+'\n'; 
}
```

If `item` is used globally elsewhere, it may be creeping in to your function's scope.  Throwing in `var` scopes `item` to the current function.

Comment: +1: I scoped the variable 'item' locally (by prefixing it withthe keyword var), and that seems to have stopped IE8 complaining. The odd thing though, is that I DO NOT have a variable named item anywhere else in my script. I'll have to investigate this further ...