# IE error on simple jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

> Detaild information about the error
>
> Useraget: Mozilla/4.0
>   (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1;
>   Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322;
>   InfoPath.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET
>   CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR
>   3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729) Tiemstamp: Tue, 25 May 2010
>   08:54:11 UTC
>
> Message: Object doesn't support
>   this property or method Row: 208
>   Character: 3 Code: 0

At row 208 i have `perpage = $("#perpage").val();`

What is wrong here? It only happens in IE8, Firefox runs it flawlessly.
Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that i had same name for **JavaScript variable** and **element id**. When i renamed the variable to **vperpage** it all worked in IE aswell.

```
vperpage = $("#perpage").val(); //Seem to work in Internet Explorer
```

Anyone that can confirm this strange behavior in IE?

*Edited 2010-05-25 13:57 GMT+1*

Just like @bobince says and the link he posted, IE sees the element and variable as the same thing if we do not declare the variable in our JavaScript.

```
var perpage = $("#perpage").val(); /*Works in Internet Explorer */
perpage = $("#perpage").val(); /*Doesn't work in Internet Explorer since 
                               we already have a element with the id perpage*/
```

This can be confusing since JavaScript itself also automatically declares a variable that doesn't exist if we give it a value. But this, as we noticed in the problem above, do not work when we already have an element with the same id. So, bad practice not to always declare your own variables :) Lesson learned!

Comment: Yes, it's well-known, which is why you should always use `var`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717240/javascript-function-works-in-ff-opera-etc-fails-in-ie8-how-to-fix

Comment: Excellent bobince. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1):

Is the element with id `perpage` anything other than form input fields? If yes, you should use:

```
var perpage = $("#perpage").html(); // for html contents of the element
var perpage = $("#perpage").text(); // for textual contents of the element
```

This could also be problematic if you have assigned the id `#perpage` to more than one element.

Comment: perpage is a select dropdown and the id is only being used once.

Comment: @jamietelin: This was not told before, thanks for clarifying that.