# Difference between variable declaration syntaxes in Javascript (including global variables)?

Tags: javascript

Is there any difference between declaring a variable:

```
var a=0; //1
```

...this way:

```
a=0; //2
```

...or:

```
window.a=0; //3
```

in global scope?

Comment: AFAIK var a = 0; does not work in IE when accessing the variable via another external js file which is declared in another js file

Comment: I donot know about window.a but the other 2 ways are the same in global scope.

Comment: @AivanMonceller really? link please.

Comment: @Raynos, I experience it on my own website. IE6 to be specific. I could not get my var enum to appear which is on an external js file and i am referencing it as an inline javascript on an html file

Comment: @Ashwini In the global scope, window is the global object (in browsers).
    var a = 1;
    console.log(a);
    console.log(win

Comment: @AivanMonceller please make a short testcase to prove this. In what order do you include js files?

Comment: @Dan , Here are related topics regarding my claim. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635018/redeclared-javascript-global-variable-overrides-old-value-in-ie , http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.lang.javascript/2008-02/msg01449.html

Answer (score 580, accepted):

Yes, there are a couple of differences, though in practical terms they're not usually big ones (except for your #2 — `a = 0;` — which A)  I strongly recommend not doing, and B) is an error in strict mode).

There's a fourth way, and as of ES2015 (ES6) there's two more. I've added the fourth way at the end, but inserted the ES2015 ways after #1 (you'll see why), so we have:

```
var a = 0;                             // 1
let a = 0;                             // 1.1 (new with ES2015)
const a = 0;                           // 1.2 (new with ES2015)
a = 0;                                 // 2
window.a = 0; /*or*/ globalThis.a = 0; // 3
this.a = 0;                            // 4
```

### Those statements explained

#### 1. `var a = 0;`

This creates a global variable which is also a property of the [global object](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/global-object.html#sec-global-object), which we access as `window` on browsers (or via the [`globalThis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis) global added in ES2020, or via `this` at global scope). Unlike some other properties, the property cannot be removed via `delete`.

In specification terms, it creates an *identifier binding* on the [Object Environment Record](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/executable-code-and-execution-contexts.html#sec-object-environment-records) for the [global environment](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/executable-code-and-execution-contexts.html#sec-global-environment-records). That makes it a property of the global object because the global object is where identifier bindings for the global environment's Object Environment Record are held. This is why the property is non-deletable: It's not just a simple property, it's an identifier binding, and identifiers can't be removed.

The binding (variable) is defined before the first line of code runs (see "When `var` happens" below).

The property this creates is enumerable (except on the very obsolete IE8 and earlier).

---

#### 1.1 `let a = 0;`

This creates a global variable which is *not* a property of the global object. This is a new thing as of ES2015.

In specification terms, it creates an identifier binding on the [*Declarative* Environment Record](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/executable-code-and-execution-contexts.html#sec-declarative-environment-records) for the global environment rather than the *Object* Environment Record. The global environment is unique in having a split [Environment Record](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/executable-code-and-execution-contexts.html#sec-environment-records), one for all the old stuff that goes on the global object (the *Object* Environment Record) and another for all the new stuff (`let`, `const`, and the functions created by `class`) that don't go on the global object, but go in the global environment's *Declarative* Environment Record instead.

The binding is *created* before any step-by-step code in its enclosing block is executed (in this case, before any global code runs), but it's not *accessible* in any way until the step-by-step execution reaches the `let` statement. Once execution reaches the `let` statement, the variable is accessible. (See "When `let` and `const` happen" below.) The time between the binding being *created* (on entry to the scope) and becoming *accessible* (code execution reaching the `let`) is called the *Temporal Dead Zone* [TMZ]. While the binding is in that state, any attempt to read from it or write to it is a runtime error.

(The specification's terminology for whether the binding is accessible is whether it's "initialized," but don't confuse that use of "initialized" with having an initializer on the `let` statement [`let a = 10;` vs. just `let a;`]; they're unrelated. The variable defined by `let a;` is initialized with `undefined` once the `let` is reached.)

---

#### 1.2 `const a = 0;`

Creates a global constant, which is not a property of the global object.

A `const` binding is exactly like a `let` binding (including the TMZ and such) except it has a flag saying its value cannot be changed. One implication of that is you must provide an initializer (the `= value` part) to provide the initial (and never-changing) value for the `const`.

Using `const` does three things for you:

1. Makes it a runtime error if you try to assign to the constant (and most IDEs will flag it up for you more proactively than that).
2. Documents its unchanging nature for other programmers.
3. Lets the JavaScript engine optimize on the basis that the `const`'s value won't change (without having to track whether it's written to later or not — e.g., doesn't have to check if it's *effectively* constant).

It's important to understand that the `const`'s value never changing doesn't mean that an object the `const` refers to is immutable. It isn't. It just means that the value of the `const` can't be changed so it refers to a *different* object (or contains a primitive):

```js
// This is fine:
const x1 = {a: 1};
console.log(x1.a); // 1
x1.a = 2;
//^^^^^^−−− No problem, just changing the object's state, not the value in the `const` (the object reference)
console.log(x1.a); // 2

// This is not:
const x2 = {a: 1};
console.log(x2.a); // 1
x2 = {a: 2};
// ^−−−−−−− Error here ("TypeError: Assignment to constant variable"),
// you can't change the value of a `const`
console.log(x2.a);
```

---

#### 2 `a = 0;`

Don't do this.  It's assigning to a completely undeclared identifier. In loose mode (the only mode before ES5), it creates a property on the global object *implicitly*. On my old blog, I call this [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). Thankfully, they fixed it with [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), added in ES5 and the default in new kinds of scopes (inside modules, inside `class` constructs, etc.). Strict mode makes assigning to an undeclared identifier the error it always should have been. It's one of several reasons to use strict mode.

Since it creates a normal property, you can `delete` it.

The property this creates is enumerable (except on the very obsolete IE8 and earlier).

---

#### 3 `window.a = 0;` or `globalThis.a = 0;`

This creates a property on the global object explicitly, using the `window` global (on browsers) or the `globalThis` global that refers to the global object. As it's a normal property, you can delete it.

This property is enumerable (*even* on the very obsolete IE8 and earlier).

---

#### 4 `this.a = 0;`

Exactly like #3, except we're referencing the global object through `this` instead of the globals `window` or `globalThis`. This works because `this` at global scope is the "global" `this` value. This is true even in strict mode. (Strict mode changes the `this` used when you call a function without supplying `this`, such as when you do `fn()`, but not what `this` is at global scope.) Note that it has to really be *global* scope. The top-level scope of [modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) is not global scope (it's *module* scope), and at module scope `this` is `undefined`.

---

### Deleting properties

What do I mean by "deleting" or "removing" `a`? Exactly that: Removing the property (entirely) via the `delete` keyword:

```js
window.a = 0;
console.log(`"a" in window? ${"a" in window}`); // "a" in window? true
delete window.a;
console.log(`"a" in window? ${"a" in window}`); // "a" in window? false
```

`delete` completely removes a property from an object. You can't do that with properties added to `window` indirectly via `var`, the `delete` is either silently ignored or throws an exception (depending on whether you're in strict mode).

*(Minor note: The very obsolete IE8 and earlier, and the obsolete IE9-IE11 in their broken "compatibility" mode, wouldn't let you delete `window` properties even if you should have been allowed to.)*

---

### When `var` happens

**Preface:** `var` has no place in new code. Use `let` or `const` instead. But it's useful to understand `var` for the purposes of understanding old code you run across.

The variables defined via the `var` statement are created before *any* step-by-step code in the execution context is run, and so the variable (and its property on the global object) exists well *before* the `var` statement.

This can be confusing, so let's take a look. Here we have code trying to access `a` and `b`, followed by code in the middle creating them, and then code trying to access them again:

```js
try {
    console.log(a);   // undefined
    console.log(b);   // ReferenceError: b is not defined
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
}

var a = "ayy";
b = "bee";            // Don't do this, but I didn't want to use `let` or `const` in this example

try {
    console.log(a);   // "ayy"
    console.log(b);   // "bee"
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
}
```

As you can see, the identifier `a` is defined (with the value `undefined`) before the first line runs, but the identifier `b` isn't, so trying to read its value is a `ReferenceError`. The statement `var a = "ayy";` really deos *two* different things, at different times: On entry to the scope, it defines the identifier with the initial value `undefined` (the `var a` part), and later when it's reached in the execution of the code, it sets the value of `a` (the `a = "ayy"` part). Since `a` is defined before the first line of code runs, we can use it (and see its `undefined` value). This is known as "`var` hoisting" because the `var a` part is moved ("hoisted") to the top of the global scope or function scope where it appears, but the `a = "ayy"` part is left in its original location. (See [*Poor misunderstood `var`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html) on my anemic old blog.)

---

### When `let` and `const` happen

`let` and `const` are different from `var` in a couple of useful ways. The ways that are relevant to the question are A) that although the binding they define is created before any step-by-step code runs, it's not *accessible* until the `let` or `const` statement is reached; and B) as we've seen above, at global scope they don't create properties on the global object.

Re (A), while this using `var` runs:

```js
console.log(a); // undefined
var a = 0;
console.log(a); // 0
```

This using `let` throws an error:

```js
console.log(a); // ReferenceError: a is not defined
let a = 0;
console.log(a);
```

The other two ways that `let` and `const` differ from `var`, which aren't really relevant to the question, are:

1. `var` always applies to the entire execution context (throughout global code, or throughout function code in the function where it appears; it jumps out of blocks), but `let` and `const` apply only within the *block* where they appear. That is, `var` has function (or global) scope, but `let` and `const` have *block* scope.
2. Repeating `var a` in the same context is harmless, but if you have `let a` (or `const a`), having another `let a` or a `const a` or a `var a` is a syntax error.

Here's an example demonstrating that `let` and `const` take effect immediately in their block before any code within that block runs, but aren't accessible until the `let` or `const` statement:

```js
let a = 0;          // (Doesn't matter whether this is `let`, `const`, or `var` [or even `class` or `function`])
console.log(a);     // 0
if (true) {
    console.log(a); // ReferenceError: a is not defined
    let a = 1;
    console.log(a);
}
```

Note that the second `console.log` fails, instead of accessing the `a` from outside the block, because within that block `a` refers to the `a` declared later in the block. But the `console.log` statement occurs within the Temporal Dead Zone for that inner `a`, so it causes an error.

---

### Avoid cluttering global scope - use modules

Global scope is very, very cluttered. It has (at least):

- Lots of global variables created via the spec (like `undefined` and `NaN` which, oddly, are globals rather than keywords; miscellanous global functions)
- (On browsers) Variables for all DOM elements with an `id` and many with a `name` (provided the `id`/`name` value is a valid identifier; otherwise, they're just properties on `window` but not global variables)
- (On browsers) Variables for `window`-specific things, like `name`, `location`, `self`...
- Variables for all global-scope `var` statements
- Variables for all global-scope `let`, `const`, and `class` statements

All of those globals are ripe with opportunities for conflicts with your code, such as this classic example on browsers:

```js
var name = 42;
console.log(name);          // 42 - seems okay, but...
console.log(typeof name);   // ...string?!?!!
```

Why is `name` a string? Because it's an accessor property on `window` for the *name* of the window object, which is always a string. (The equivalent with `let` would work as expected, since the declarative environment record is conceptually nested within the object environment record, so the `name` binding created with `let` shadows the `name` binding for the accessor property.)

Whenever possible, don't add to the mess. Use modules instead. Top-level scope in modules is *module scope*, not global scope, so only other code in your module sees those top-level declarations. You can share information between modules via `export` and `import`.

Before modules, we used "scoping" functions wrapped around our code:

```js
// From the ES5 era
(function () {
    var a = 0; // `a` is NOT a property of `window` now

    function example() {
        console.log(a);   // Shows "0", because `example` can access `a`
    }
    
    example();
})();
```

Modules make that obsolete.

Comment: can i do `window['a']=0`to make it clear i'm using window as a map?  is `window` special such that some browsers don't allow this and force me to use `window.a`?

Comment: One note on **#3** that's probably worth clarifying: `window.a = 0;` only works in browser environments, and only by convention. Binding the global object to a variable named `window` is not in the ES Spec and so will not work in, for example, V8 or Node.js, while `this.a = 0;` (when invoked in the global execution context) will work in any environment since the spec *does* specify that there must be *a* global object. If wrapping your code in an IIFE as in the **Off-topic** section, you can pass `this` as a parameter named `window` or `global` to get a direct reference to the global object.

Comment: @Sherlock_HJ: I've added "on browsers;" that is earlier in the answer as well, but I added it in case people skip down to that. It [is in the spec now](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-global-object); while it's only in passing, you won't find a browser that doesn't do it. I'm a bit surprised it's not in [Annex B](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-additional-ecmascript-features-for-web-browsers).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, So, a global variable declared with `var a = 0;` automatically becomes a property of the global object. If I declare `var b = 0;` within a function declaration, will it also be a property of some underlying object?

Comment: @ezpresso: No and yes. They do become properties of an object (the *EnvironmentRecord* of the *VariableEnvironment* of the *ExecutionContext* where they appear; details [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-variable-statement) and [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-execution-contexts)), but there's no way to directly access that object from program code.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, thanks! It greatly explains the variable hoisting phenomena. Can't we then say, that in JavaScript all the variables are in fact properties of the EnvironmentRecord internal object?

Comment: @ezpresso: Yes, all variables are properties of an EnvironmentRecord object (in specification terms, anyway; in terms of implementation, the JavaScript engine is free to do what it likes and smart ones *will* use stack if they can). Note that even within a single execution context, at any given time there may multiple EnvironmentRecords, although usually there's only one. This is to handle things like `with`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, what's the point that variables declared in a global scope are made available as a properties of the window object? Is it for backward compatibility with legacy JavaScript code?

Comment: @ezpresso: More accurately, vars at global scope become properties of the global object. On browsers, the global object's variable environment record is also the `window` object. It's just how JavaScript was originally defined by Brendan Eich during those 10 days in May in 1995. I think it's generally considered a mistake now, including by Eich, since the new `let`, `const`, and `class` at global scope *don't* create properties on the global object (only `var` and function declarations). So going forward, you can have global vars that aren't properties on the global object.

Comment: I like the sentence **It's not just a simple property, it's an identifier binding**

Answer (score 40):

Keeping it simple :

```
a = 0
```

The code above gives a global scope variable

```
var a = 0;
```

This code will give a variable to be used in the current scope, and under it

```
window.a = 0;
```

This generally is same as the global variable.

Comment: Your statements *"The code above gives a global scope variable"* and *"This code will give a variable to be used in the current scope, and under it"*, taken together, suggest that you can't use the first line and access `a` *under* the current scope. You can. Also, your use of "global variable" is a bit off -- the two places you say "global variable" are no more global than the place you don't say it.

Comment: global itself means that you can access/read/write the variable anywhere, including the place where i mentioned current scope, that is so obvious. And if you suggest that window.a and 'a' wont be global in the script then you are 100% wrong.

Comment: If you declare a = 0; or window.a = 0; then these both variables can be accessed anywhere on the page, under any script and any scope. and I said they both are generally the same thing because you can access window.a by just a, and vice versa.

Comment: @Umair: *"global itself means that you can access/read/write the variable anywhere"* Right. Again, you seem to be calling out the first and last as more "global" than the middle, which of course they aren't.

Comment: the middle one is considered to be used inside a function, all of them would be same if used under the main scope. using var inside a function was my assumption

Comment: @Umair: *"using var inside a function was my assumption"* Ah, okay. But that's not the question. The question very clearly says *"in global scope"*. If you're going to change the assumption (which is fair enough, to expand and explain a more general point), you'll need to be clear that's what you're doing in your answer.

Answer (score 10):

```
<title>Index.html</title>
<script>
    var varDeclaration = true;
    noVarDeclaration = true;
    window.hungOnWindow = true;
    document.hungOnDocument = true;
</script>
<script src="external.js"></script>

/* external.js */

console.info(varDeclaration == true); // could be .log, alert etc
// returns false in IE8

console.info(noVarDeclaration == true); // could be .log, alert etc
// returns false in IE8

console.info(window.hungOnWindow == true); // could be .log, alert etc
// returns true in IE8

console.info(document.hungOnDocument == true); // could be .log, alert etc
// returns ??? in IE8 (untested!)  *I personally find this more clugy than hanging off window obj
```

Is there a global object that all vars are hung off of by default? eg: 'globals.noVar declaration'

Comment: Very nice exploration. The definite guide to using `window.*` declaration. This declaration looks most safe against copy-pasting your code, and clear also.

Answer (score 8):

Bassed on the excellent answer of **T.J. Crowder**: (**Off-topic: Avoid cluttering `window`**)

This is an example of his idea:

**Html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="init.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      MYLIBRARY.init(["firstValue", 2, "thirdValue"]);
    </script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello !</h1>
  </body>    
</html>
```

**init.js** (Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2190927/2954267))

```
var MYLIBRARY = MYLIBRARY || (function(){
    var _args = {}; // private

    return {
        init : function(Args) {
            _args = Args;
            // some other initialising
        },
        helloWorld : function(i) {
            return _args[i];
        }
    };
}());
```

**script.js**

```
// Here you can use the values defined in the html as if it were a global variable
var a = "Hello World " + MYLIBRARY.helloWorld(2);

alert(a);
```

Here's the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/iE0Vr7sszfqrrDIsR8Wi?p=preview). Hope it help !

Answer (score 5):

In global scope there is no semantic difference.

But you really should avoid `a=0` since your setting a value to an undeclared variable.

Also use closures to avoid editing global scope at all

```
(function() {
   // do stuff locally

   // Hoist something to global scope
   window.someGlobal = someLocal
}());
```

Always use closures and always hoist to global scope when its absolutely neccesary. You should be using asynchronous event handling for most of your communication anyway.

As @AvianMoncellor mentioned there is an IE bug with `var a = foo` only declaring a global for file scope. This is an issue with IE's notorious broken interpreter. This bug does sound familiar so it's probably true.

So stick to `window.globalName = someLocalpointer`

Comment: *"In global scope there is no semantic difference."* Actually, there's a huge semantic difference, the mechanisms by which the property gets defined are completely different -- but in practical terms it boils down to only a small *actual* difference (in that you can't `delete` a `var`).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I didn't know that. I thought variable declaration was setting properties on the variable object. Didn't know those couldn't be deleted.

Comment: Yup. They're also defined earlier if you use `var`. They're just completely different mechanisms that have much the same practical result. :-)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I forgot to mention that `var` jumps to the stop of scope.