# window.variableName

Tags: javascript

I am going through some code and at the beginning of the script we have `var emailID = email`. Later on, the code refers to emailID by going `window.emailID`. I am wondering what are the rules that allow you to refer to a variable by going window.variableName?

I cannot post my script online as it is directly related to my work and would violate my contract.

Comment: Note: For future reference, it should be safe to post a small snippet of code that's similar to the code you're working with, something that illustrates what you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

`window.variableName` means that the variable is being declared at the global scope.  This means any JS code will have access to this variable.  Using `window.` is not necessary but is frequently used as a convention to denote that a variable is global.

Globals are generally to be avoided.  You should define variables within the scope of functions.

Comment: Why do people use this for creating a global variable inside a function when the can simply create a variable outside the function and then modify the variable inside the function?

Comment: @Shaya if, for some reason, you do not have access to that function or its return value in the context you require it (in some rare usages of a delegate, for example)

Answer (score 29):

Global variables in JavaScript are attached to the "global object", which in a browser environment is aliased to `window` object - this is why you can refer to a global variable either as `variableName` or `window.variableName`.

It's also worth mentioning that using global variables in JavaScript is not considered good coding practice.

Here's a [good and very detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4862268).

Answer (score 18):

`window.myVar` or `window["myVar"]` is an explicit way to refer to a global variable.

A variable is a global variable if it's declared outside of a function (with or without "var"), or if it's declared inside a function without using "var", or if it's declared as `window.myVar` or `window["myVar"]`.

A variable is declared by either assigning a value to it, or by using the keyword `var`.

One case where it's useful to refer to a global variable as `window.myVar` is if you're inside a function that has a local variable called `myvar`. In that case, `myVar` refers to the local variable, while `window.myVar` refers to the global variable.

Answer (score 14):

Global Variables in JavaScript

```
var no =10;
function getNo()
   alert(no); // 10
}
getNo();
```

When a global variable is set, it's added to the window object!

```
var no =10;
function getNo()
   alert(window.no); // 10
}
getNo();
```

We can direct set window variable.

```
function setNo(){
  window.no=100;
}
function getNo()
   alert(window.no); // 100
}
setNo();
getNo();
```

Answer (score 2):

For pure theoretical explanations (as I encountered this "issue" myself) and easy to digest information you can look at the problem as this:

var myName = "Bob" equals to - globalObject(Window) = { myName: "Bob" }

so when you declare a variable, that variable name is passed to the window object as a property and it's value as a property value. That's why you can call the variable as an object method of the window object, basically.

Answer (score 0):

It is used to define global variable in JavaScript.

```
globalVar = "Hello World";
function function1(){
    alert(window.globalVar);
} 
function1();
```

This will print "Hello World" in the popup.

```
    function function1(){ 
        globalVar = "Hello World";
        alert(window.globalVar);
    }function function2(){
        alert(window.globalVar);
    } 
    function1(); 
    function2();
```

This will create two popups with value "Hello World", one from function1() and another from function2().

So, by using window we can call a variable from any scope in javascript.