# jQuery EasyUI tabs Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, jquery-easyui

I created some tabs using [jQuery EasyUI tabs](http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/tabs.php). The content of the tab is loaded by Ajax because I pass the `href` attribute to my tab like:

```
<div id="mytabs" class="easyui-tabs" style="width:500px;height:250px;">  
    <div title="Tab1" href="/app/controller/tab_content" style="padding:20px;">  
        tab1  
    </div>  
    <div title="Tab2" href="/app/controller/tab_content" style="padding:20px;">  
        tab2  
    </div>  
    <div title="Tab3" href="/app/controller/tab_content" style="padding:20px;">  
        tab3  
    </div>  
</div>
```

As you can see above, every time a tab is selected, the action `tab_content` which contains the content to be displayed in the tab panel (/app/controller/tab_content is just for illustration) is called. All of this work fine, but what I'm trying to do is to make a variable available to the view `tab_content.ctp` when the url is called (WITHOUT passing it as a parameter in the url) like:

```
/app/controller/tab_content/my_variable:test
```

Is there any way that I can pass a variable to my view when the tab is clicked without passing it to the url of the tab content? In order words, I want `my_variable` to be available to the view `tab_content.ctp` when the tab is clicked.

Note: This is a cakephp application

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You might have solved the problem already, but I ran into a similar issue with EasyUI tabs and remote content and thought I might share it. What I ended up doing was

- for the variable to be passed: declare it as a `window.variable`, i.e. by setting `window.my_variable = my_variable`
- for the external tab content: call the variable via javascript in the external file - since a `window.variable` has global scope, it is also available in dynamically loaded content (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11149036/1531565) answer)

Hope this is of help.

Answer (score 0):

Edit `jquery.easyui.min.js` and search for:

```
$.fn.panel.defaults
```

Change  method: "get"  to method "post"