# Why does the following 3 line code return 1?

Tags: javascript

I'm reading a book on JavaScript called Eloquent JavaScript. The following is a snippet from the book:

"The two main ways to access properties in JavaScript are with a dot and with
square brackets. Both value.x and value[x] access a property on value—but
not necessarily the same property. The difference is in how x is interpreted.
When using a dot, the word after the dot is the literal name of the property.
When using square brackets, the expression between the brackets is evaluated to
get the property name. Whereas value.x fetches the property of value named
“x”, value[x] tries to evaluate the expression x and uses the result, converted
to a string, as the property name."

While playing around with this bit of information, I happened to try this bit of code. It returns the value at the first index of the array. Why so?

```
arr = [1,2,3];
len = "length";
console.log(arr[len]);
```

// Output is "3" as expected

```
arr = [1,2,3];
console.log(arr.length);
```

//Output is "3" as expected

```
arr = [1,2,3];
len = "length";
console.log(arr[length]);
```

//Output is "1"

//The output I was expecting was an error or at least the value "3" since JS is a flexible language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the zeroth element of arr is 1

i.e. you probably meant to do this

arr[len]

length itself is zero, hence the you are really doing this arr[0]

length is window.length, which this link explains

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_length.asp

(Added later)

The confusion seems to be around length being the same as window.length.
The links below may help with understanding that, although if you're a beginner I'd probably just accept it and return to it later

[window.variableName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148997/window-variablename)

[Difference between variable declaration syntaxes in Javascript (including global variables)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862193/difference-between-variable-declaration-syntaxes-in-javascript-including-global/4862268#4862268)

Comment: Yes I figured as soon as I posted the question that it was returning the 0th index value. But why is it returning that

Comment: "length itself is zero"  -- how did it get initialized to 0?

Comment: I do explain that, because length (number of iframes on the window) is 0.

Comment: You may not realise that when you type length it's actually shorthand for window.length

Comment: Oh yes. Just read that. Wasn't aware of the concept of iframes. Thank you tony

Answer (score 3):

You can't use variable names as strings.

`length` has a value of `0` (because it is the same as `window.length`, which actually [represents the number of frames in the current document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/length)), so you're seeing the first element of the array:

```js
let arr = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
console.log( length );      // 0
console.log( arr[length] ); // 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You take the [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/length), which is a property of `Window` and returns the number of frames of the window.

```js
console.log(length); // 0
```