# Javascript innerWidth instead of window.innerWidth

Tags: javascript

Is there any reason why should I use `window.innerWidth` instead of `innerWidth`?

Comment: Someone can create a variable named `innerWidth` and you wouldn't get desired result

Comment: Possible duplicate of [window.variableName](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11148997/1823841)

Comment: Also, it's clearer at a glance what the innerWidth is referencing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.innerWidth` is always a property of the window object, so you're safe as long as a window exists (in other js environments like Node.js it doesn't), while `innerWidth` refers to the global object only if there isn't already a variable with the same name in the current scope.

For example

```js
// This logs the actual window.innerWidth
console.log(innerWidth);

function something() {
  const innerWidth = 4;

  // This innerWidth will not refer to the global object..
  console.log(innerWidth);
}

// ..so this logs 4
something();
```

So either you remember all of the `window` properties so you don't incur in conflicting variable names (not very handy and hard to debug) or you just access the `window` object explicitly, making the code a little more verbose but also clearer and less error-prone.