# Set dynamically variables accessible with this. from an external file in VueJS not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a settings.js file that only contains definitions :

```
export default {
  maintenanceMode: 'yeahhhhh',
  enableRegister: false,
}
```

In order to make these settings available from everywhere in my app with this.$maintenanceMode for example, I added this, which works perfectly, to my main.js :

```
 Vue.prototype.$maintenanceMode = globalSettings.maintenanceMode
 Vue.prototype.$enableRegister = globalSettings.enableRegister
```

But when I try to assign values dynamically like this in my main.js :

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(globalSettings)) {
  Vue.prototype['$' + key] = globalSettings[value]
  })
}
```

or like this :

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(globalSettings)) {
  Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$' + key, {
    value: globalSettings[value],
  })
}
```

this.$maintenanceMode is undefined...

Does anyone has already done something similar or can point me where is my error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to do this:

```
 Vue.prototype.$maintenanceMode = globalSettings.maintenanceMode
 Vue.prototype.$enableRegister = globalSettings.enableRegister
```

Just import those constants from settings.js file wherever you need them:

```
import * as settings from './settings'
```

EDIT >>>
You can always assign variables to 'window' object, in order to reach them globally:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148997/window-variablename#:~:text=When%20a%20global%20variable%20is,can%20direct%20set%20window%20variable.&text=so%20when%20you%20declare%20a,value%20as%20a%20property%20value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148997/window-variablename#:%7E:text=When%20a%20global%20variable%20is,can%20direct%20set%20window%20variable.&text=so%20when%20you%20declare%20a,value%20as%20a%20property%20value).

but the way I suggested at first is widely accepted way of handling global constants in JavaScript

Comment: You are right but my primary goal was to only import it once for the entire app because their values will accessed from a lot of different places. The main problem is why my loop isn't working.