# accessing a variable from window object in IE8 does not work

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have the following script:

```
xxx = 12232;
for (var j in window) { 
    if (j==='xxx') alert('hey');
}
```

If I execute in Chrome or Firefox I get the alert-dialog printing 'hey'.

If I execute in IE8 I don't.

Obviously,this is a snippet of code to prove that I can not access a variable from window in IE8.

Can somebody explain why that is ?

Comment: you should take a look at this for more info [Javascript global variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862193/javascript-global-variables).

Comment: @nameIsNull yep. I did take a look. Not the same question but very useful info there too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What that snippet shows isn't that you can't access the [implicit global](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) in IE8, it shows that implicit globals in IE8 are not [enumerable](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6.4), which is a totally different thing.

You can still access it just fine:

```
display("Creating implicit global");
xxx = 12232;
display("Enumerating window properties");
for (var j in window) { 
  if (j==='xxx') {
    display("Found the global");
  }
}
display("Done enumerating window properties");
display("Does the global exist? " + ("xxx" in window));
display("The global's value is " + xxx);
display("Also available via <code>window.xxx</code>: " +
        window.xxx);

function display(msg) {
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.innerHTML = String(msg);
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

[Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/eyubej/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/eyubej/1/edit)

For me, on IE8, that outputs:

```
Creating implicit global
Enumerating window properties
Done enumerating window properties
Does the global exist? true
The global's value is 12232
Also available via window.xxx: 12232
```

On Chrome, the global is enumerable:

```
Creating implicit global
Enumerating window properties
Found the global
Done enumerating window properties
Does the global exist? true
The global's value is 12232
Also available via window.xxx: 12232
```

Implicit globals are a **Bad Idea<sup>TM</sup>**. Strongly recommend not using them. If you **have** to create a global (and you almost never do), do it explicitly:

- With a `var` at global scope (which, on IE8, seems to also create a non-enumerable property)
- Or by assigning to `window.globalname` (which, on IE8, creates an enumerable property)

I've added these results (which are, to me, a bit odd) to my [JavaScript global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4862268/157247) answer that talks about different kinds of globals, since I hadn't touched on enumerability there.