# Var & JavaScript Variable Scope

Tags: javascript, html, variables, global-variables, scope

**JS Code**

```
    var foo = "Hello World!"; // <------- global scope
    document.write("<p>Before our anonymous function foo means '" + foo + '".</p>');

    (function() {
        // The following code will be enclosed within an anonymous function
        var foo = "Goodbye World!"; // <------- local scope
        document.write("<p>Inside our anonymous function foo means '" + foo + '".</p>');
    })(); // We call our anonymous function immediately

    document.write("<p>After our anonymous function foo means '" + foo + '".</p>');
```

**HTML Output**

```
Before our anomymous function foo means 'Hello World!".

Inside our anomymous function foo means 'Goodbye World!".

After our anomymous function foo means 'Hello World!".
```

My problem is

- When we replace the value of `foo` variable inside the function why
  does not get it replaced ? How does it still contains the `"Hello World!"`?
- If I'm to access the global variable inside the function How can I do it ?

Comment: Isn't it the same in all coding languages? scoping and inner scope isn't quite js unique behavior though it has it's "uniqueness".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `var foo` inside your function, you are explicitly telling the variable only to change locally, within that function. If you want to change it globally, just use `foo = ...`

If you want to read up on it, I suggest [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope/500459#500459)

Answer (score 1):

remove the `var` statement from the anonymous function and you will alter the global variable:

```
var foo = "Hello World!"; // <------- global scope
document.write("<p>Before our anonymous function foo means '" + foo + '".</p>');

(function() {
    // The following code will be enclosed within an anonymous function
    foo = "Goodbye World!"; // <------- local scope
    document.write("<p>Inside our anonymous function foo means '" + foo + '".</p>');
})(); // We call our anonymous function immediately

document.write("<p>After our anonymous function foo means '" + foo + '".</p>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are shadowing the global variable with a function scoped variable. To access the global variable you can explicitly say so with window.foo

```
var foo = "Hello World!"; // <------- global scope
document.write("<p>Before our anonymous function foo means '" + foo + '".</p>');

(function() {
    // The following code will be enclosed within an anonymous function
    var foo = "Goodbye World!"; // <------- local scope
    document.write("<p>Inside our anonymous function foo means '" + foo + '".</p>');
    document.write("<p>Inside our anonymous function window.foo means '" + window.foo + '".</p>');
    window.foo = window.foo + foo;
})(); // We call our anonymous function immediately

document.write("<p>After our anonymous function foo means '" + foo + '".</p>');
```

this will print "Hello World!Goodbye World!"

Comment: O/P is Inside our anonymous function window.foo means 'undefined".

Comment: The global decleration of var = "Hello World!" adds it to the window object making it accesable from within the anonymous function.
Here is a post about window scoping http://stackoverflow.com/a/4862268/2033671