# Using 'window' with a local variable for global access in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables

I'd like to access a local variable globally (without changing the namespace or location of the variable). I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862193/javascript-global-variables/) that I could use 'window.', but it's not working:

```
var myNameSpace = {
        window.localVar : 'foo'
    };

alert(window.localVar);  // Not working
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gKWNr/)

Can something like this work?

Also, I've read about the risks of global variables. If I'm nearly certain a variable's name isn't at risk to be reused, is it safe?

```
$myTotallyUniqueVarName
```

Comment: *"but it's not working:"* ... well, using `window.lovalVar` is syntax error at this position: `but it's not working: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`.

Comment: Re *"Not working"*: In what way is it not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var myNameSpace = { };

myNameSpace.localVar = window.localVar = 'foo';
```

You can't access another object when defining the *key* from another object, like you tried. But you certainly can create multiple references/assignments to the same value, like shown above.

However, be aware that we assigning a *primitive value* in this case, that means, `window.localVar` and `myNameSpace.localVar` will hold their own unique value. Any change will **not** reflect on the other side.

Answer (score 1):

Every variable that is somehow related to the global object can be accessed globally. In browsers, the window variable represents the global object.

```
function a() {
  bvar = 3; // Accessible
  var cvar = 4; // Inaccessible
}

a();

alert(window.bvar === 3); // true
alert(window.cvar === 4); // false, cvar is undefined

// This refers here to the global object
alert(window.bvar === this.bvar); // true
```

Comment: thanks, that's helpful. so bvar is accessible because it's a key, or because it isn't a variable?

Comment: In JavaScript everything can be seen as an array. So, a function is an array with properties, and the global object can be seen as a array to. The function a() and bvar are both 'items' / properties on the global object. (every variable declared without the var prefix will leak into the global object.) so, window.a and window.bvar are accessable. cvar is declared inside a function and becomes a property of the functions' activation object'. Properties of activation object of functions are not accessable outside the function scope. Hope this helps, space is little here to explain this.

Comment: @Andries: I'd rather say everything is an object. Arrays are special types of objects.

Comment: @Felix: True, thats why i carefully expressed myself by saying 'can be seen as'. I wanted to stress the array-behavior of JavaScript like: window['cvar'] === window.cvar. But you also right. Maybe we should say, everything is an special type of an object.:)