# save clicked element´s path in variable

Tags: javascript, events

my html:

```
<form action="submitPage.php" method="post" onsubmit="savePathInVar();"> 
  <table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="<?php echo $path; ?>" onclick="changecolor(this);" /></td>
    <td><img src="<?php echo $path; ?>" onclick="changecolor(this);" /></td>
  </tr>
    <input type="hidden" value="ClickedImaged" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />          
  </table>
</form>
```

ps: `$path = "inventory_images/$id.jpg";`
my function changecolor():

```
function changecolor(img)
{
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for(var i=0,j=images.length; i<j; i++)
{
    images[i].style.borderColor="#000";
}
img.style.borderColor="#F00";
//Operate on img location as before
savePathInVar(img.src);
}
```

my function savePathInVar():

```
function savePathInVar(ImgLocation)
{
//How do i save the path of the clicked image in a variable now?
}
```

How do i save the path of the clicked image in a variable now?
And how do i get this variable into my input-hidden-field below my table?
Anyone who can help me?
would be really nice if anyone could help me.. i am quite new to javascript :) greetings!

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but you want to save the path of the clicked image in a string, and save this string in the value of your input? In this case, it's pretty simple. Notice the added names of the form and the input.

```
<form name="form_name" action="submitPage.php" method="post" onsubmit="savePathInVar();"> 
  <table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="<?php echo $path; ?>" onclick="changecolor(this);" /></td>
    <td><img src="<?php echo $path; ?>" onclick="changecolor(this);" /></td>
  </tr>
    <input name="input_name" type="hidden" value="ClickedImaged" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />          
  </table>
</form>

function savePathInVar(ImgLocation)
{
    //if you want it to be a local variable
    var str = ImgLocation;
    //if you want it to be a global variable - to be handled with care*
    str = ImgLocation;
    document.form_name.input_name.value = str; 

}
```

* Be careful when you use global variables. You can find a bit more details here: [Difference between variable declaration syntaxes in Javascript (including global variables)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862193/javascript-global-variables)

Comment: yes, i want to save the path of the clicked image in a string and so on :) by clicking on "submit" i want to output the "path" of the chosen image. so this is my submitPage.php:                                 `$clickedImage = $_POST['ClickedImaged'];
echo $clickedImage;`                     But i just get "ClickedImage" displayed, not the path, whats wrong? greetings

Comment: I'm not familiar with php, so I can't say exactly what your program is doing. However, what is your $_POST['ClickedImaged'];? Are you sure you have the right parameter value? in the forme, the "ClickedImaged" is simply the value displayed, it is not an id or a name.

Comment: so what do i have to write/add to display the path of the clicked image in submitPage.php ?

Comment: I have no way of testing, but I'm guessing it should be something similar to $_POST['input_name'];

Answer (score 0):

Just save the var and then set it to the field.

```
var imgLoc;

function savePathInVar(ImgLocation)
{
    imgLoc = ImgLocation
    document.getElementById('hiddenImgLoc').value = ImgLocation
}
```

Example: (I've removed the hidden attribute on the field so you can see it.)
http://jsfiddle.net/E4RG3/