# Kendo Datasource variable

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I would like to know whats the difference between

```
        states_datasource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "<?php echo BASE_URL . 'user/get_state_autocomplete'; ?>",
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: "results"
            }
        });
```

AND

```
    var states_datasource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "<?php echo BASE_URL . 'user/get_state_autocomplete'; ?>",
                dataType: "json"
            }
        },
        schema: {
            data: "results"
        }
    });
```

I was working with an editable listview with edit template which has an autocomplete field - which uses the above mentioned datasource.

In the edit mode, I did not get it working with the second datasource, but the datasource was binded and working for the first datasource.

Just wondering what could be the reason?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript global variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862193/javascript-global-variables)

Comment: Thanks OnaBai, :) looks like I have to learn some javascript basics first :D