# How can I prevent this infinite loop, if I don’t know content of function

Tags: javascript, inheritance

How can I isolate my variable from variable in this function, if his creator forgot for var keyword?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
{
    test();
}

function test() 
{
    i = 0;
}
```

Comment: Call it `myAwesomeIndex`.

Comment: Run your code in strict mode, so you'll get an error in modern browsers when creating implicit variables. Otherwise, scope your code to a new variable scope.

Comment: **Make** the function's creator add the `var` keyword :-)

Comment: Javascript global/local variables http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862193/javascript-global-variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same idea than previous answer using scoping but a better way would be to use IIFE:

```
(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        test();
    }
})();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8vBc5/

Comment: I believe you mean IIFE. IIEF is, erm, something else.

Comment: @Alan ... ermmm... Would that make it more of a `disfunction` than a `function`?

Answer (score 3):

put your for loop in a separated *scope*:

in a function.

```
function test(){
  i = 0;
}
function trial(){
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    test();
  }
}
trial();
```

That way only the code and functions inside the `trial` function can access variables declared at that level.