# deleting a window property in IE - try/catch throwing error too

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

So I have a window property variable that I need to delete, and of course IE hates the `delete` method. I've tried the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4862268/341611), like so:

```
try {
   delete window.locator_init_in_progress;
}
catch (e) {
   window.locator_init_in_progress = undefined;
}
```

Now I get the following error in IE8:

[image]

What do I need to do to make this stop throwing errors and work in IE8? (I'm assuming it's the `try` part that's throwing the error, but this code will not pass our QA process if there are any errors in the console, so what do I need to do so this works? Should I just abandon the try/catch and do a test for user-agent, and if it's IE8, set the property to undefined?

**UPDATE**

Yes, the variable is defined. I've added some alerts in, since IE8 can blow up on console.logs. Here's my current code:

```
// window.ie8orearlier is a global variable that is set 
// based on user agent string; in this case it's correctly 
// evaluating to true when testing in IE8

if(window.ie8orearlier && window.locator_init_in_progress!= undefined && window.locator_init_in_progress == true) {
   alert("ie8 and value is set; not undefined");
   window.locator_init_in_progress = undefined;
}
else if(window.ie8orearlier && window.locator_init_in_progress == undefined) {
   alert("ie8 and undefined; do nothing");
}
else {
   alert("else");
   delete window.locator_init_in_progress;
}
```

It's consistently hitting the "ie8 and value is set; not undefined" alert. The error, as far as I can see (IE8's dev tools not providing line numbers for errors), is being thrown by the line trying to set the value to undefined.

Comment: Post more info.  Are you sure that's the point where it's failing?

Comment: has is been _defined_ in the first place ?

Comment: Yes, it's been defined. I'm updating the OP with more info.

Comment: `(function(window.locator_init_in_progress)){ window.locator_init_in_progress = undefined; }();` Wrap this into `IIFE` and tell it to allow overriding, that should work.

Comment: What is IIFE? And what am I allowing to be overridden?

Comment: As you know if you try to do something like this : `document = null` or `window = null` it will throw an exception too. `Immediately-Invoked-Function-Expression` (IIFE) allows to override non-override able object and properties within its body. `(function(window, document){  window = null; document = null;  /* Now both window and document are null, but within its body only*/ })();`

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is a documented issue in IE8 - see Kangax's thorough write-up on the `delete` keyword [here](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/#ie_bugs). Trying to use `delete` to remove any object property, not just `window` properties, in IE 8 throws an error.

I would recommend simply setting `locator_init_in_progress` to `undefined`. Is there a particular reason you need the property removed? I've found that setting a property to `undefined` is often safer than using the `delete` keyword because delete doesn't always behave the way developers think it will.

Comment: If you note, I'm *trying* to set it to undefined. It's still throwing the error.

Comment: Even completely getting rid of all if/try-catch stuff and just setting the variable to undefined throws the error. IE8 just really doesn't seem to like `undefined`.

Comment: Hm, perhaps it doesn't like having properties set on "window"? Can you try instantiating another global variable and putting the property on that?

Comment: Unfortunately no. This is a small but frequently-used part of a huge codebase. It works in all other browsers; I can't start changing the variable for one browser.

Comment: And the annoying thing is that the IE8 dev tools doesn't even give me a line number on the thrown error, so I'm guessing at where it's happening. It may not even be the piece I'm dealing with; I just happened to know that IE doesn't like delete so tried to replace it with undefined. It may actually be some other piece of code entirely that's throwing the error.