# ie7 script error line 0 char 0 code 0 jquery 1.10.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I'm adding some social share links to a site. In the HTML, I just have basic links like:

```
<a class="facebook_share" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php">Facebook</a>
```

I'm using jQuery 1.10.1 to append parameters (current page url and, for some social networks, the current page title) to the link href. Here's an example:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
"use strict";
var $title = $(this).attr('title');
var $href = $(location).attr('href');
// Facebook
var fb_url = $("a.facebook_share").attr("href");
$("a.facebook_share").attr("href", fb_url + "?u=" + encodeURIComponent($href)); // add  encoded version of current page href to FB url
});
```

In IE7, I'm getting "error on page" as follows:
Line: 0
Char: 0
Error: Script error
Code: 0

So in IE7, the parameters don't get added to the link href.

Chrome, F'fox are OK. IE8 is OK now I'm testing on public server but was giving "line 5: object doesn't support this property or method" when I was testing on my local WAMP server.

Test page with links to 4 networks here:

http://test-interact.co.uk/test_social_share_links.htm

Comment: Keep in mind that Internet Explorer tends to run in a different mode when you're running it on a local domain (aka intranet). There is a way to turn it off but I've forgotten how.

Comment: Why are you doing `$(this).attr('title')` and `$(location).attr('href')`?  Try using `document.title` and `location.href`.  jQuery should only be used for DOM elements.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen: "Tools" (press `Alt` if your menu bar is hidden) > "Compatibility View Settings".  There's a checkbox for `Display intranet sites in Compatibility View`.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen - in fact IE7 doesn't do this. In IE8 and higher, the mode you're thinking of puts them into IE7-compat mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is in regards to properties vs attributes.  Attributes are set, and then do not change, properties change.  Thus, properties on the document/page etc. (title, href) change and can be accessed as changed, the attributes retain the original value and do not change when they are "really" a property.

These access the "document" attributes:

```
var $title = $(this).attr('title');
var $href = $(location).attr('href');
```

These access the current property values:

```
var $title = document.title;
var $href = location.href;
```

Comment: See this for properties on the "window" object as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862193/javascript-global-variables

Answer (score 2):

jQuery's `$()` function is only meant for "wrapping" DOM elements.

```
var $title = $(this).attr('title');
var $href = $(location).attr('href');
```

Chances are, this is what's breaking it in IE7.  This is not the correct way to access these properties.

Try using the native properties:

```
var $title = document.title;
var $href = location.href;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not access to the title by DOM, you must use `document.title` variable

```
var title = document.title
```

should solve the problem

Comment: He's not editing the title, but I still agree with using `document.title` vs `$(this).attr('title')`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $title = document.title;
var $href = location.href;
```