# What's the difference between mopen(m1) and mopen('m1') in a function?

Tags: javascript, html

The function used  in below program....
Why we use single quote in function mopen('m1') instead of mopen(m1)

```
<ul id="sddm">
    <div id="m1" onmouseover="mcancelclosetime()" onmouseout="mclosetime()">
        <a href="#">HTML DropDown</a>
        <a href="#">DHTML DropDown menu</a>
        <a href="#">JavaScript DropDown</a>
        <a href="#">DropDown Menu</a>
        <a href="#">CSS DropDown</a>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#" onmouseover="mopen('m1')" onmouseout="mclosetime()">Home</a>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- `mopen(m1)` gives the `m1` declared viarable as an argument to the function `mopen`.
- `mopen('m1')` gives the string literal `'m1'` as an argument to the function `mopen`.

**UPDATE**

Updating accordingly to @Frogmouth's and @MazeHatter's comment :

In your case `mopen(m1)` will trigger a `ReferenceError: m1 is not defined` unless the variable `m1` is defined somewhere as [a global](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4862268/1665540) in your javascript code.

Comment: +1 ... simply and well explained. - only one thing `m1` variable must be defined before be use.

Comment: Using a variable that doesn't exist causes an error, not simply passing an undefined value.

Answer (score 2):

That would of course depend on what mopen() does. And strangely enough, I must've borrowed the same code as you for a project, mopen() looks like this:

```
function mopen(id) {

// cancel close timer
mcancelclosetime();

// close old layer
if(ddmenuitem != null) ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'hidden';

// get new layer and show it
ddmenuitem = document.getElementById(id);
ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'visible';

}
```

You see here that the parameter you sent is *id*, which then gets sent to *document.getElementById(id);*

getElementById() expects a string, the id of the menu item in the HTML.

In this case its

```
<div id="m1"
```

So you pass in the string "m1".

Without the quotes *m1* is a variable reference. Since you have no variable called *m1*, it would cause an error if you tried to read it.

Answer (score 0):

```
mopen('m1'); //you pass m1 as a string

mopen(m1); //mp1 an object or a variable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var m1="Shoaib"
```

1. mopen(m1);
2. mopen('m1');
3. mopen();

   ```
   function mopen(methodOpen){

    alert(methodOpen+" is opened");
   }
   ```

First case output will be `Shoaib is opened` in alert box as `m1` is consider as variable which you are passing to method.

Second case you are passing `direct value` as String 'm1'
so output will be `m1 is opened` in the alert box.

Third case as you are not passing any variable so it will take as undefined
So output will be `undefined is opened`