# JavaScript variable creation in global scope + strict mode

Tags: javascript

In global scope, is there a difference between

```
this.myvar = 42;
```

and

```
var myvar = 42;
```

?

(In strict-mode, if that matters.)

And if so, what is the difference, esp. when referencing `myvar` in functions?

(The question might be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862193/javascript-global-variables).)

Comment: The first is effectively `window.myvar = 42;` :)

Comment: @Jack: Only if `this === window`, which is not the case for me. :) (I'm running pure V8.)

Comment: Yes there is difference

Comment: Welcome Paul sir! Albert is having 11 kilogram Reputation,How can i help i am poor ,200 reputation

Comment: `this` refer always to current context and here context is `global`.

Comment: I think you may have answered your own question there ;-)

Answer (score 0):

No There is no difference. in global scope. but if you go inside a function and say '`this`' it still refers to window. that's why normally when go deep into function developers normally equalize `var self = this;` before go to function and use `self.variableName;`

Comment: I thought, in strict mode, a function in global scope, if I just call it by name, has `this === undefined`. I would have to call it like `this.myFunc()`.

Answer (score 0):

In a global scope, `this === window`.

So, `this` is a simple accessor to `window` (like a pointer in `C` or a reference in `PHP`).

In the facts, assigments likes `var x = 'toto'` can be fetched with:

`console.log(window.x);`

`console.log(x);`

`console.log(this.x);`

### Example:

```
var x = 'toto'; // assignment before mythis definition

var mythis = (function(self) { // mythis definition
    return self;
})(this);

var y = 'tata'; // assignment after mythis definition

console.log(mythis.x); // display toto
console.log(this.x); // display toto
console.log(window.x); // display toto

console.log(mythis.y); // display tata
console.log(this.y); // display tata
console.log(window.y); // display tata
```

### Live example:

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EpICH)