# Passing object/class as arguments

Tags: javascript, prototype

Below is my module pattern.

```
var Application = (function ($, window, undefined) {

}(jQuery, window));
```

Is there any way i can load my other Class/Object as params?. For instance, if i have a file named `Helper.js` inside `Utils` directory which by again is a module pattern. Can i pass it as a `argument` like below and use it in my Application class so that i can avoid usage of `global variables in my class.`

```
var Application = (function ($, window, undefined) {

}(jQuery, window, Helper));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define your `Helper` as a local variable (using `var`), it will not clutter the global scope.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Helper = (function() {
       var helper = { ... };
       return helper;
    }());
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var Application = (function ($, window, helper) {

    }(jQuery, window, Helper));

<script>
```

Learn more about globals: [Difference between variable declaration syntaxes in Javascript (including global variables)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862193/javascript-global-variables)

And a good tool to use for implementing the module pattern is to use a module loader, check out [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html)

Comment: Thanks, Just a question. There are two files Helper.js and Application.js. Can i still load Helper in Application.js. I am slightly getting confused here...

Comment: Yes they can be separate files, I'm just illustrating what the contents would be. It would be equivalent because the browser executes the JavaScript content as soon as it sees the `<script>` tag (and downloads it)

Comment: @theJava By the way, highly recommend using RequireJS because it takes care of the module variable scope and module dependency for you automatically.

Comment: At the end of the day all becomes local variables and can be injected and used in different files across. right?

Answer (score 1):

This should be what you need, just pass it as a parameter of your module and stick it just before `undefined`, you can do it as many times as you need modules.

```
var Application = (function ($, window, Helper, undefined) {

}(jQuery, window, Helper));
```