# How to call a method on a function OR how to redraw Highcharts dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, highcharts, coffeescript

While this questions is based around Rails and Highcharts, I suspect that the real issue is my poor javascript abilities.

I'm trying to add a Highcharts chart to a Rails 3.2 app that will all a user to dynamically update the data shown via an ajax call.

So far I have the chart displaying on page load, but am unable to get the chart to redraw when the user selects new data. From reading related questions on SO and elsewhere, I think I need to use Highcharts `setData` method. However, due to the way my code is structured, I'm unsure how to call this method on the chart.

My code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready ->
  if $("#graph_container").length
    fetchData $('#graph_container').data('id') 
fetchData = (id) ->
  params =
    method: "graph_data"
    date_from: $("#date_from").val()
    date_to: $("#date_to").val()
  $.ajax
    url: "/events/" + $('#graph_container').data('id')
    type: "GET"
    async: true
    data: params
    dataType: "json"
    success: (data) ->
      plotData data
plotData = (data) -> 
  options =  
    series: [{
      name: 'Events',
      data: data
    }]
  $("#graph_container").highcharts options
```

This is working perfectly when the page loads. I now want to bind the refresh to a click event. From what I've read I need to do something like

```
jQuery ->
  $("#refresh_btn").click ->
    params =
      method: "graph_data"
      date_from: $("#date_from").val()
      date_to: $("#date_to").val()
    $.ajax
      url: "/events/" + $('#graph_container').data('id')
      type: "GET"
      async: true
      data: params
      dataType: "json"
      success: (data) ->
        chart.setData(data)
```

But in these example the chart is named variable

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options)
```

How should I modify my code, so that I can call the `setData` on my plotData function. I suspect this is a very rudimentary javascript question - I'd be very grateful for an explanation that would help me learn.

Comment: The chart will be in a global object, `Highcharts.charts[0]`, not sure how you use that within coffeescript, maybe just `Highcharts.charts[0].setData...`  I'm still trying figure why people use coffeescript :)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your code to use the constructor rather than the jQuery initialiser:

```
plotData = (data) -> 
  options =
    chart:
      renderTo: $('#graph_container')
    series: [{
      name: 'Events'
      data: data
    }]
  chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options)
```

The `renderTo` option tells Highcharts which element to render the chart into. Otherwise it’s the same.

If you plan to use `chart` outside `plotData`, you’ll have to store a reference to it so it’s accessible. The simplest way would be to attach it to `window`, but global variables are frowned upon.

Comment: thanks Buck. accessing `chart` outside `plotData` is the part that is confusing me. Can you recommend any references/ tutorials that explain this in more detail?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862193/javascript-global-variables) is some reading about that. But if you don’t care about such purist considerations, which maybe you shouldn’t if this is a small application, just define the variable as `window.chart = …` and then you’ll be able to use it elsewhere.