# Javascript delete operator

Tags: javascript, memory-management, properties

I read a book about javascript that said:

```
var o = {x:1 , y:2 };
delete o ; // Can't delete a declared variable so returns false;
```

However, the book also states that the variables declared outside any function scope are properties of the global object.

Why aren't we allowed to delete it then if it is a property of the global object?

Comment: try it without the `var` keyword. http://jsbin.com/nohocozeqini/1/edit

Answer (score 3):

By saying:

`var o = {x:1 , y:2 };`

in the top level scope, you are declaring a global *variable*, which can not be deleted. It does create a property on the global object (which is aliased to the `window` object in browsers), but it is a special property indeed. However, if you make the declaration like:

`o = {x:1 , y:2 };`

then you are setting a property on the global scope (remember, the `window` object) implicitly. The two are similar, but different enough. The `delete` operator removes an implicit property from an object, but will not delete a variable created on the global object.

**Edit, found a more thorough answer**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4862268/1443478

Comment: I would specify here that by `o = {x:1 , y:2 };` we are setting _property_ of window **object** (so we can refer to it as `window.o`), which is the same, but sounds more clear in terms of `delete` definition.

Answer (score 1):

Since O is already declared and have properties you cannot use delete on the object. You can use

```
var o = {x:1 , y:2 };
delete o.x ;
```

and delete properties here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zg4zh3r8/1/) for the same.

Comment: `o = {a:true};

delete o;

console.log(window.o); //undefined`

Comment: downvote explained by my comment. I can delete it. In my jsbin in the comment to the question, I can see it. maybe i'm wrong. I'll upvote if you can provide a bit more clarity.

Comment: you never initialized it and is without a var. the question is with a var. hence tried to explain it with it only.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment.

Answer (score -1):

first you have to know what is the work of delete operator.let me explain---

```
"The delete operator removes a property from an object".here i say it removes an object property not a variable.

in your code you declare a variable.not an object so delete does not work.i think you understand.
```

`o = {x:1 , y:2 };
  delete o ;`

but the code above is right i think. why?
because here o is a property of the global object which is also an object so it work properly.the link which can help you is [delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

it is my first answer.be happy with coding.