# Is it possible to declare variable dynamically in jquery as a global variable?

Tags: jquery

So i want to declare variable according to my loop. so i have done the following

```
 $.each(filter,function(key,value){
    var value;
   });
```

my filter array contains:

```
Geo_Name_date,Geo_Gender_date,Geo_Age_date,Geo_Ethnicity_date,Geo_Race_date,Geo_Language_date,Geo_Smoker_ind_date,Geo_Primarycare_provider_name_date
```

When i alert after the loop over. the variable should alert undefined. But its giving reference error.  any suggestion or what am doing wrong? is it possible to do like this?

Comment: `value` is a local variable in the function. After the loop is done, the variable is gone.

Comment: you are getting `value` as parameter in `function(key,value)` and you are trying to define `value` again that you cannot. try some other name.

Comment: make value in the global scope

Comment: Yea just now found that. Can you provide me some suggestion on getting that globally.

Comment: If you want to create a global variable, don't use the `var` keyword, and use a different name than the parameter.

Comment: `this.a= 0;` or `window.a = 0;`

see: [javascript-global-variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862193/javascript-global-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should preferably create properties in an object rather than global variables:

```
var values = {};
$.each(filter, function(key, value) {
  values[value] = undefined;
});
```

It's possible to create global variables dynamically. You should avoid creating a lot of variables in the global scope, but if that is really what you need, you can use the `eval` method to assign values to the variables in the loop without declaring them. That will create them in the global scope:

```
$.each(filter, function(key, value) {
  eval(value + '=undefined');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To assign a global variable, leave out the `var` keyword:

```
$.each(filter, function(key, value) {
    globalValue = undefined;
});
alert(globalValue); // Will show undefined
```

Comment: Hey Barmar, So i have tried something like this but it not seems to be working.


   $.each(filter,function(key,value){
 value=undefined;
   });
 
   alert(Geo_Name_date);