# What does `var` do in the global scope?

Tags: javascript, html

In an HTML `<script>` tag, outside of any function, does `var` have any meaning?

Is there any difference between these three notations?

```
<script>
  var a = 1;
  b = 1;
  window.c = 1;
</script>
```

Comment: No, in the global scope it doesn't because you're defining it locally in the global scope which is the same thing as defining it in the global scope without `var`.

Comment: Using `var` is faster, however: http://jsperf.com/var-in-global-scope (tiny micro-optimization, you shouldn't sacrifice quality in your code)

Comment: @TheWobbuffet— the *var* keyword has exactly the same meaning in global code as it does in function code—it creates a variable in the current execution context. There are at least two significant differences between declared variables and properties assigned to the global (window) object.

Comment: @RobG Yes, so I assume not using var is slower in the global scope because it has to keep going up on the hierarchy until it finds the global object

Answer (score 1):

At the top level (outside all functions) `var` declares a global variable.

To avert this, wrap your code in a function.

```
(function () {
    var a = 1;
}());

'a' in window;
// => false
```

Despite that each form declares a global variable, they have subtle differences. `var` creates an undeletable property on `window`, and is subject to typical hoisting rules whereby the property will exist on `window` at the start of the `var` statement's execution context. The other forms create a deletable property on `window` at the time that the line of code is executed.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4862268/1468130) for more info.

Comment: Can you elaborate? "Is there any difference between these three notations?"

Comment: They are the same in that context.

Comment: Thanks. So you don't need var at all, outside a function?

Comment: Technically no, but I recommend the third form, because the intent of the code is clearest. The first form implies the the variable should have been localized, and the second form is better used to reference variables which are already defined.

Comment: @RobG You're right. The statement "They are the same in that context." is not true. I have updated my post to elaborate on this.

Answer (score 0):

In your simple, unlikely example, there is no difference, but there are a few subtle differences that can result in hair-pulling if you decide to make a habit of not declaring variables "since they are the same."

You can read up on these differences at the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var), my go-to on questions like this.

Summarizing briefly the main reasons `b = 1` is bad:

- Browsers in strict mode will throw an exception on `b = 1`.
- From within a function, only `var a = 1` will be scoped to the function. It will be unclear whether you intend for `b = 1` to be global or not. If you're mutating that variable, one day you're going to wonder why the heck you're getting different results from the same exact function with the exact same parameters.