# Private variable visible in console?

Tags: javascript, console.log, iife

I've got the following code block:

```
(function(){
  a = 1; 
  alert(a);
})();
```

When I open the console in Chrome, I can see the variable `a`, with a value of `1`. Shouldn't it be invisible since it's in an IIFE?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html): You never declare `a`, and so the statement `a = 1;` creates a global variable, not a local one. (In loose mode. Thankfully, nowadays we have *strict mode*, in which that extremely strange behavior was changed to be the error it always should have been.)

If you add a `var` in front of `a`:

```
var a = 1;
```

...it'll be private, and you won't have access to it within the console **except** when paused on a breakpoint within that function. When you're paused on a breakpoint within the function, everything in scope within the function is in scope to the console (to make the console more useful).

It's *really easy* to accidentally create global variables in loose mode:

```
function foo() {
    var niftySpiffyThing;

    // ...

    niftySpiffything = 42;

    // ...
}
```

Call `foo` once and *bam*, you have a global called `niftySpiffything` (because of the lowercase `t` in `thing`).

This is one of many reasons to habitually use strict mode, by putting `"use strict"` at the top of the script or as the first expression within a function:

```
"use strict"; // Applies to all code in this script
(function(){
  a = 1; 
  alert(a);
})();
```

or

```
(function(){
  "use strict"; // Applies only to code within this function
  a = 1; 
  alert(a);
})();
```

Then you get an error instead of a global.

Comment: Wow, thank you! Didn't realize that was the case even in an IIFE.

Comment: @FloatingRock: It's true for all functions. :-)

Answer (score 3):

`a = 1` means that a is a global varialbe, it is not private.
Write

```
var a = 1;
```

to make it private.

When you omit `var`, you can easily create global variables - very dangerous.

Some materials are here: [Difference between variable declaration syntaxes in Javascript (including global variables)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862193/javascript-global-variables)

Comment: Thanks! `var a = 1` fixed it .. it's `"use strict"` from now on