# accessing form variables (e.g. input tags) in javascript function: Is it better to pass the value or use a selector to acces it? (javascript/jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently passing all variables to the function. I'm just wondering if there's a negative to this method or is it better to just access the form variable via a jQuery selector e.g. `$("#namefield").val()`.

Maybe passing the value is better from a security/readability POV?

I did search the net but came across nothing on this topic.

Here is a sample code to what I'm using now.

```
<form>
     <input id="myname" name="myname" type=text">
</form>
<script>
     doSomething($("myname").val());

     function doSomething(myname) {
          console.log(myname);
          //console.log($("#myname").val());
     }
</script>
```

Comment: you can use global vaiable ?   read more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862193/javascript-global-variables