# Where do local variables go?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

Lets say I have a

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Eucalyptus</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color: #FFE11A">
    <div id="gore" style="background-color: #BEDB39">gore
        <button id="prvi" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; border-radius:10px;">Kurac</button>
        <div id="drugi">Drekec</div>
    </div>
    <div id="dolje">dolsdasdje</div>
    <script>
    var AAA1 = 1;
    (function(a, b) {
        var AAA3 = a + b;
        AAA2 = a * b;
    })(10, 10);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I can obviously see `window.AAA1` and `window.AAA2` but where is AAA3?
Is it possible to hook it somehow and edit it on the fly from the console or is it just jumbled somewhere in machine code and not accessible anymore?

Comment: Answer on your question can be found here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with `<script>`, the title is misleading. `AAA3` is locally scoped to the function. You might want to read up on variable scope.

Comment: Can I somehow access it without changing the code which ran at start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AAA3` is a `local` variable and it can't be access outside the `function` or current scope.

> Variable declarations, wherever they occur, are processed before any code is executed. The scope of a variable declared with var is its current execution context, which is either the enclosing function or, for variables declared outside any function, global.

Learn more about JavaScript variable's scope at:

[MDN JavaScript Variable scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

[Stackoverflow JavaScript Variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

**Edited:**

Looked at [Javascript Global Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862193/javascript-global-variables). It has a lot of information which might be useful to you.

Comment: Is it still possible to somehow access it through chrome dev console?  Like from some pool of invoked functions from where you can still access their values?

Comment: NO. you can't access it. May be you can `alert` it or `console.log` to check the value inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript variable created either at functional scope or global scope.

Here  **var AAA3** is created  at functional scope and it is stored on stack memory.

Once function execution is completed, data segment created for that function on stack is popped and memory hold for the local variable is released.
So,they are not available after the function execution is completed.

Answer (score 0):

It is enclosed within the scope of the function in which it is created. If you want it accessible on the global scope, do window.AAA3 = '??';

Refer to this other answer for an overview of JavaScript scope:

[What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)