# Javascript global variable 'table'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to set global variable 'table' in chrome console and the result is :

```
var table=5;
table
function table(data, [columns]) { [Command Line API] }
```

'table' isn't a reserved variable so why I cant set it to something else?
Thanks.

Comment: `console.table` is the issue it appears

Comment: also, `var table = 5` is global variable when it is placed top priority

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a global because Chrome uses `__commandLineAPI` as the global object in the console.

It looks something like this:

```
with (typeof __commandLineAPI !== 'undefined' ? __commandLineAPI : { __proto__: null }) {
   // code executed in the console goes in here.
}
```

If you'd like a list of the functions in that object, you can run `Object.keys(__commandLineAPI)` and it will output this:

```
["$$", "$x", "dir", "dirxml", "keys", "values", "profile", "profileEnd", "monitorEvents", "unmonitorEvents", "inspect", "copy", "clear", "getEventListeners", "debug", "undebug", "monitor", "unmonitor", "table", "$0", "$1", "$2", "$3", "$4", "$_"]
```

I guess you can wrap it in a closure if you really need to:

```
(function() {
   var table = 1234;
   console.log(table);
})()
```

Or if you want to just overwrite it in the `window`, just do `window.table = ...`

Answer (score 1):

See this question about [global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862193/javascript-global-variables)

you could try `window.table` or `this.table` if you truly need a global variable.

if you set `window.table = 5;` and then echo `table` in the console you will see the value that you set to `window.table`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a prefix: `var app_table = 5;`