# JSON printing objects value recursively

Tags: json, recursion

I'm trying to build a tree using JSON for which i'm trying to just print in browser console.

```
var json = [{
  name: "1",
  id: 1,
  child: [{
    name: "11",
    id: 11,
    child: [{
      name: "111",
      id: 111
    }, {
      name: "112",
      id: 112
    }]
  }, {
    name: "12",
    id: 12
  }]
}];

function ya(obj) {
  console.log(obj.name);
  if (obj.child) {
    console.log("length=" + obj.child.length);
    for (i = 0; i < obj.child.length; i++) {
      ya(obj.child[i]);
    }
  }
}
ya(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json))[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here I would like to print

> 1
>   11
>   111
>   112
>   12

in console. But it only prints

> 1
>   11
>   111
>   112

I want to do this recursively. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `i` with `var`:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < obj.child.length; i++)
```

See [Difference between variable declaration syntaxes in Javascript (including global variables)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862193/javascript-global-variables) for more details.