# Event_Bus vue variable access to single file component Vue.js - Laravel Mix

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-mix

I just want to ask on how to access a variable to the single file component of vue? 
When i try to access my app on the browser the vue js will result an error.

> Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: EventBus is not defined"

My code below.

I implement this on the app.js

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
var EventBus = new Vue();

    Vue.component('transactionslist', require('./components/TransactionList.vue'));

    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#transaction',
        methods: {
            getTransactions: function () {
                $.getJSON("/guard/station/transactions?search=" + this.Search, function (_transactions) {
                    this.Transactions = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(_transactions));
                }.bind(this));
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                Search: '',
                Transactions: [],
            }
        },
        mounted: function () {
            this.getTransactions();

        }
    });
```

and this is my vue component (TransactionList.vue)

```
<template>
    <table class="table table-hover transaction-list">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="fit">Transfer Code</th>
                <th>Orgin</th>
                <th>Destination</th>
                <th class="fit">Date Created</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <transactionRow @rowSelected="isSelectedRow" v-for="trans in data" :origin="trans.Origin" :destination="trans.Destination"
                :date="trans.created_at" :key="trans.TransferCode" :tscode="trans.TransferCode">
            </transactionRow>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['data'],
        created() {
            this.transactions = this.$children;
        },
        data() {
            return {
                transactions: [],
                Transaction: []
            }
        },
        methods: {
            isSelectedRow: function (payload) {
                EventBus.$emit('showSelected', payload);
                this.transactions.forEach(transaction => {
                    transaction.isActive = (transaction.tscode == payload.tscode);
                });
            },
        }

    }
</script>
```

I develop the application using laravel and I use one of laravel feature which is the laravel Mix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use this:

```
window.EventBus = new Vue();
```

Comment: Hello! Well, `window` is a global object for client side, so you assign a variable to it and can use it on this page. [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862193/difference-between-variable-declaration-syntaxes-in-javascript-including-global/4862268#4862268)

Answer (score 2):

You just defined the `EventBus` in the app.js file.

It is not accessible in the TransactionList.vue component as it has no reference to the `EventBus`

So export the `EventBus` in your app.js as

```
export const EventBus = new Vue();
```

And then import the `EventBus` in your components script as

```
<script>
    import {EventBus} from './path/to/app.js'
    export default {

    }
</script>
```

See es6 [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and [export](https://www.google.co.in/url?q=https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjB6fnMgO7ZAhUBOY8KHWqcDAoQFggSMAE&usg=AOvVaw3vdMfU_sbr_YJcJPstSAUZ)

Comment: hi sir i have tried this one but it will error during the npm compilation.

Answer (score 1):

Create the event bus in it's own file:

```
// bus.js
import Vue from 'vue'
const bus = new Vue()
export default bus
```

The import it into the components you want to use it in:

```
import bus from 'bus'
export default { 
   ...
   methods: {
       myMethod () {
           bus.$emit('my-event', 'test')
       }
    }
   ...
}
```