# Can't access window["var_name"] with Webpack Encore

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, webpack-encore, material-components-web

Based on the code below, I have a varaible `mdcDialog`, which is initialized with `material-components-web` (MDCDialog) library once page is loaded.

On form submit, default event is prevented and instead, `ajaxSubmit()` handle the form.
The response is a json object, from which I can find the variable `response.modal.modal` with it's string value `mdcDialog`.

But for one reason or another, `console.info(window[response.modal.modal]);` return undefined instead of the variable `mdcDialog`.
On the other hand, doing `console.log(mdcDialog)` output the variable as it should.

How can I access my variable `mdcDialog` from a string response if `window` isn't working?

<kbd>**app.js**</kbd>

```
/* --- VARS --- */
const page="#page";
let mdcDialog;

/* --- FUNCTIONS --- */
function ajaxSubmit(node) {
    $.ajax({
        type: node.attr("method"),
        url: node.attr("action"),
        enctype: "multipart/form-data",
        data: new FormData(node[0]),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false
    }).done(function(response, status, xhr) {
        if(response !== false) {
            /** @var response.modal */
            if(typeof response.modal !== "undefined") {
                /** @var response.modal.action */
                /** @var response.modal.modal */
                /** @var response.modal.content */
                if(response.modal.action === "load") {
                    console.info(window[response.modal.modal]);
                }
            }
        }

    }).fail(function(request, status, error) {
        console.error(request);
        console.error(status);
        console.error(error);
    });
}

/* --- ACTIONS --- */
$(document).ready(function() {
    mdcDialog=new mdc.dialog.MDCDialog(document.querySelector("#dialog-level.mdc-dialog"));

    $(page).on("submit", ".ajs", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        ajaxSubmit($(this));
    })
});
```

Comment: not absolutely certain, but in the browser console, if you enter `console.log(mdcDialog)` does it give you the contents of the variable? otherwise, why not set `window.mdcDialog = new mdc.dialog......` to make sure it's actually in the global scope? I could imagine webpack compiling it into some local scope var.

Comment: yes @Jakumi, if I do `console.log(mdcDialog)`, it gives me the variable.

Comment: I have to assume, that you did not enter `console.log(mdcDialog)` *in the browser console* (which would check in the global scope) but instead you put that statement somewhere in the code, where it might access the local scope instead. otherwise, your comment directly contradicts the answer you chose as a solution.

Comment: I use `console.info` most of the time @Jakumi, sorry, I wrote `console.log` above, was my mistake.

Comment: I'm not so much worried about log vs info, but more about the place where you put that ... browser console (F12 in most browsers) vs. somewhere in a function

Comment: Ah~ was inside the code, not via the console (F12) itself @Jakumi. My bad, I tends to fly over the text, and have only read the part about doing a console.log. Didn't notice the browser console part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables defined with `let` or `const` have block scope, and even if they are defined in the outermost scope, they won't be defined *globally* and therefore [will **never** be accessible through the global (`window`) object.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Scoping_rules_2)

To make them accessible that way, you **have** to use `var`, or to define them on the global object itself.

```js
let foo=1
window.foo //undefined
foo        //1

var bar=2
window.bar //2
bar        //2

window.baz=3
window.baz //3
baz        //3
```

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4862268/8376184) for more information

Comment: I see, that why I can't access it. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: That answer is partially wrong, using `var` won't set it on `window` either since the file is processed by Webpack and treated as a JS module.

Answer (score 2):

You are only defining `mdcDialog` within the scope of this function (if javascript is running in "Strict Mode"):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    mdcDialog=new mdc.dialog.MDCDialog(document.querySelector("#dialog-level.mdc-dialog"));

    ...
});
```

To give it global scope and make it accessible via `window['mdcDialog']` do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.mdcDialog = new mdc.dialog.MDCDialog(document.querySelector("#dialog-level.mdc-dialog"));

    ...
});
```

Or define it in the global scope before the function:

```
var mdcDialog;
$(document).ready(function() {
    mdcDialog = new mdc.dialog.MDCDialog(document.querySelector("#dialog-level.mdc-dialog"));

    ...
});
```

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Comment: it's defined in the global scope. 3rd line of my code

Comment: Ok, I didn't see that but what happens when you change that line to `window.mcdialog = null;` (no `let`)?

Comment: if I do `window.mdcDialog=new mdc.dialog.MDCDialog(document.querySelector("#dialog-level.mdc-dialog"));` it works, I can read `window['mdcDialog']`. But, it dsoesn't tell me, in my current code, where was set my varaible if it's not in `window` scope by default. My need is to find where my variable is. I got tons of variables in scope, and there is a reason why webpack scope isn't global.

Answer (score 1):

Your app.js file is treated as a JavaScript module which means that variables you declare in it are, by default, scoped to that module and not added to `window` (which is usually a bad thing to do).

If you want to make something available outside of your module (in another file or from your HTML page / webtools), you can set `global.mdcDialog`.

That being said I'm not sure what you are trying to do in your example... if you need to access the instance of `mdc.dialog.MDCDialog` created in the `$(document).ready` callback, why wouldn't you directly use `mdcDialog`?

If your use case is "I will have multiple dialogs and will need to retrieve the right one" maybe storing all instances in an object would be a better way to do it:

```
const dialogs = {};

function ajaxSubmit(node) {
    $.ajax({
        // ...
    }).done(function(response, status, xhr) {
        // ...
        console.info(dialogs[response.modal.modal]);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    dialogs['mdcDialog'] = new mdc.dialog.MDCDialog(/* ... */);

    $(page).on("submit", ".ajs", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        ajaxSubmit($(this));
    })
});
```