# In javascript, 'var' behaves different with any object called "name", it logs the object as [object Object]. Why does this happen?

Tags: javascript, object, var, let

```
var name={id:"12"}
console.log(name) // logs [object Object]
```

But the following variations log the object correctly

```
//Variation 1-changing "name" to "name1"
var name1={id:"12"}
console.log(name1) // logs {id:"12"}

//Variation 2-changing "var" to "let"
let name={id:"12"}
console.log(name) // logs {id:"12"}
```

Why does this happen?
Edit:-This is different from any other questioner-let question on stack overflow!

Comment: No, it's really not different from the other question. A global `var name` does nothing because `window.name` is already defined, and `window.name` is type-locked to a string.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4862268/12407908) (to a different question) describes your variation #2. You're basically asking about the difference between `var` and `let` in the global scope. The answer I linked is *very* comprehensive.